Inference of T in case of nested class in C++
I was trying to implement an iterator class declared inside my custom vector class and encountered a problem when I tried to overload the "+" operator outside of the vector class. Here is a simplified version of my code.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    T t{};

    struct InnerA {
        InnerA operator+(int n) {
            return *this;
        }

//        friend InnerA operator+(int n, const InnerA& a) {
//            return a;
//        };
    };

    A operator+(int n) {
        return *this;
    }
};

// OK
template<typename T>
A<T> operator+(int n, A<T> a) {
    return a;
}

// Candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
template<typename T>
A<T>::InnerA operator+(int n, const typename A<T>::InnerA& a) {
    return a;
}

int main() {
    A<int> a;
    auto a1 = a + 1;
    auto a2 = 1 + a;  // OK

    A<int>::InnerA b;
    auto b1 = b + 1;
    auto b2 = 1 + b;  // CE
}

I can't figure out why the compiler can't infer the type T in the second case without a friend declaration in the parent class. Nevertheless, I can overload the operator of the parent class A without declaring the overloading function as a friend.
I expect that in the second case, the compiler can infer the type T without a friend declaration.
